# Obtain the upper bound for a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Let $c_1>0$ and $0<a<1$ be real numbers. How to argue that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that 
$$a^{c_1\ln T}\leq T^{-C}$$
for all sufficiently large $T$, or even better, for all $T\in\mathbb{N}$?

The paper that I'm reading says that such $C$ exists but I'm not completely sure about it. Both sequences of the forms $a^{c_1\ln T}$ and $ T^{-C}$ converges to zero as $T\to \infty$. But to satisfy the inequality above I should pick $C$ so that $ T^{-C}$ converges to zero not faster than $a^{c_1\ln T}$ (otherwise the ratio of them would diverge).

**My attempt**

For all $T\in\mathbb{N}$, taking logs both sides
\begin{align}
a^{c_1\ln T}\leq T^{-C} &\iff c_1 \ln T \ln a\leq \ln 1-C\ln T\\
&\iff c_1\ln a\leq -C
\end{align}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set $b=a^{c_1}$, then $b^{\ln T}=(e^{\ln b})^{\ln T}=(e^{\ln T})^{\ln b}=T^{\ln b}$, now notice that since $a<1\rightarrow \ln a<0$, so set $C=-\ln b=-c\ln a$

Comment: @Alessandro Oh thanks! The same of my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a\in(0,1)$, there must be some $C>0$ such that $a^{c_1}=e^{-C}$. So take $C=-c_1\log a$. Then

$$T^{-C}=T^{c_1\log a}=T^{\log a^{c_1}}=(e^{\log T})^{\log a^{c_1}}=(e^{\log a^{c_1}})^{\log T}=a^{c_1\log T}.$$